# How to use variables in Azure CLI step in Azure CI/CD

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to deploy my configuration settings using Azure CLI step in my release pipeline.

There are multiple commands in it that I need to run which looks like this.

```
 - *az webapp config settings set -g resourceGroupName -n WebAppName
   --settings somekey=somevalue*
```

Note that There is a `resourcegroupname` and `webappname` that are present in it.
How Can I create a Variable for those two values and use them in my CLI.
I have tried adding them to the arguments but it didn't work.

Getting below error

```
validation error: Parameter 'resource_group_name' must conform to the following pattern: '^[-\\w\\._\\(\\)]+[^\\.]$'.
```

The reason being that I have 30 odd values and I need to create those variables for webapp which is present in multiple resource groups, So that I can simply swap the name of resource group and run the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define variable in your pipeline and then use them in Azure Cli step.

[image]

So if you have variable named `ResourceGroup` you should have

```bsh
az webapp config settings set -g $(ResourceGroup) -n WebAppName --settings somekey=somevalue
```

You can also create [variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and reuse it across your pipelines.